# Generate variables from SQL database

Tags: c#

I work on a project where I gather data from an SQL server.

I need to read 2 columns out of the database. The amount of rows can differ each time.

What I want to do is create variables modular to the amount of rows it has read.
An example:

I have 2 columns with the names: Name, Status.

In this table I have 10 rows. What I want my code to do is when it reads the data, it needs to create variables with the names from the Column Name and with the value of the column status.

So that would mean that when my code is done I have 10 new variables with the Names from Column: Name. And the values of those variables are the values from the column: Status.

Is there a proper way to do this?

Edit here is my test code:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
  string F_Name = reader.GetString(0);
  string status = reader.GetString(1);
  list.Add(F_Name);
  list.Add(status);
}
```

Comment: You could use a `Dictionary` I suppose (you can populate the `Dictionary` from the data reader)... what have you already tried?

Comment: @AStopher I've tried to push them in an array or add them to a list, but I can't seem to link the 2 together. So when I push them to an array I just push it as a string and then on place [0] there is the name and on place [1] is the status. But I want them to be on the same spot.

Comment: Looks like your problem is deciding what type of object that data should be stored in. Can it have duplicated values?If it cannot, what columns identify uniquely a row? The `Name`? Both `Name` and `Status`?

Comment: "_I've tried to push them in an array or add them to a list, but I can't seem to link the 2 together_" That looks like you could provide some code to improve the question and allow others understand your problem better

Comment: @bradbury9 If I understand you question correctly, the name column will alway hold a unique name. The status is a 1 or a 0.

Comment: So you could use a `Dictionary<string, bool>` as AStopher suggested. Hard to know without any code if that is all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a dictionary like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var row in rowsFromDb)
{
    string name = row["Name"].ToString();
    string status = row["Status"].ToString();
    dict.Add(name, status);
}
```

A `Dictionary` is a data structure that could have many entries, and each entry has an index and a value, so they are linked (as you want).

And you can access the values of a dictionary this way:

```
string status = dict["VariableName"];
```

Comment: And read about the Dictionary in the Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1